# drag and drop of swc components

Tags: apache-flex

We need a capability by which we can drag and drop swc components in our Flex Application.

Any ideas would help.

Thanks

Comment: It will be good if you can elaborate the question so that others can have a better understanding of the challenge you are facing and offer you a solution.

Comment: Are you actually willing to load `unknown` modules (classes) at runtime into your application, or you'd like to visually drag/drop known components/instances loaded from swc libraries inside your application?

Answer (score 0):

SWC is ZIP archive. You can unpack it with any ZIP library, inside you'll find catalog.xml, where library classes are listed (script.@name), and library.swf. You can load it with Loader.loadBytes after extraction in your ApplicationDomain. Knowing class names, you can get classes with getDefinitionByName.
Just curious - what your application is going to do with unknown classes in runtime?